# Cannot install TinyTex on Windows - access is denied

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, tinytex

I've been trying to install TinyTex from RStudio using `tinytex::install_tinytex()` and bumped into the issue of `Access is denied` at the end of installation. I use corporate laptop with Windows installed, but I'm having a local administrator privilages. From what I noticed it looks like installation was finished, although is not complete.

`tinytex::tinytex_root()` returns the following directory: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX", but from I noticed this directory is not set in PATH variable (although I restarted RStudio after installing latex). I also tried to install TinyTex using `tinytex:::install_prebuilt()` but it resulted in `Access is denied` error as well.

When I'm trying to compile the test.Rmd file I get:

```
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\username~1\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "test.tex"'
Execution halted
```

Therefore, I'd like to ask if there is anything what I can do to get TinyTex properly installed? Can I at least navigate to which directory should I have access to finish the installation?

Here's the output of `xfun::session_info('tinytex')`:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362), RStudio 1.2.5042

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
  LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

Package version:
  graphics_3.6.3  grDevices_3.6.3 stats_3.6.3     tinytex_0.22    tools_3.6.3     utils_3.6.3     xfun_0.13
```

Comment: Just for the record, this was later cross-posted to https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/208.